# How to do Histogram Equalization for many colored images in python?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, histogram, opencv

I have many colored images in `.png` extension format with their default names `right.1.png`, `right.2.png`, ... and `right.n.png`, also `wrong.1.png`, `wrong.2.png`... and `wrong.n.png`. I want to do histogram equalization in *python* by using any library numpy, cv2 etc for all the images. I am supposed to save the equalized images with their default names in a new folder call it `NEWFOLDER` in the current working directory.

I have tried to follow the following link for grayscale images but I could not succeed [How to implement histogram equalization for images in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835247/how-to-implement-histogram-equalization-for-images-in-tensorflow)
Any suggestions to handle this

Comment: I believe in OpenCV, cv2.equalizeHist works only on grayscale images. You would have to do it channel by channel. Python Wand allows you to do it on all channels at the same time. See equalize at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html. Note that Imagemagick will need to be installed to use Python Wand. But it comes on most Linux distributions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am using windows but I will try to look around and inform you of any success about the matter. @fmw42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histogram equalization is pretty straight-forward with opencv. [Here's](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html#histograms-equalization-in-opencv) the documentation.

```py
# Histogram equalization

def hist_equal(file_name):
    # Read image file
    img = cv2.imread(DIR_PATH + file_name, 0)
    # Apply histogram equalization
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    # Save file to new directory
    cv2.imwrite(NEW_DIR_PATH + file_name, equ)
```

To iterate through the file in a directory, you can make use of the `os` library in Python.

```py
# Iterate through each image file
for file_name in os.listdir(DIR_PATH):
    hist_equal(file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the documentation and a good trial for solving the problem. I have read through and implemented for grayscale images as shown in the above link.
I was thinking that **maybe cv2 is applicable for RGB images** What I want seems to be similar like this link here [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/histogram-equalization-a-simple-way-to-improve-the-contrast-of-your-image-bcd66596d815). This is done for only one colored image. I need to do it more than 100 images

Comment: You can just loop through all the file one at a time, apply the histogram equalization and save each new image in the new directory.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, even though I have accepted the answer by @skillsmuggler but I am trying to loop using the link in the first comment unsuccessfully. How can I use the module in this link [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/histogram-equalization-a-simple-way-to-improve-the-contrast-of-your-image-bcd66596d815). I am trying to loop for 700 images, I get an error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)`